# Unknown error in mpl_finance candlestick. What to do?

Tags: pandas, numpy, matplotlib, python-3.6, candlestick-chart

Please forgive my ignorance, I've had a look around and can't find an answer to my question. Any and all suggestions would be much appreciated
I'm trying to print OHLC Candlestick data from an API and am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test5.py", line 53, in <module>
    candlestick_ohlc(ax1,ohlc_df.values,width=1, colorup='g', colordown='k',alpha=0.75)
  File "/Users/MBP/Python_world/py_env1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mpl_finance.py", line 731, in candlestick_ohlc
    alpha=alpha, ochl=False)
  File "/Users/MBP/Python_world/py_env1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mpl_finance.py", line 784, in _candlestick
    height = close - open
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

Here is my code:

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
from mpl_finance import candlestick_ohlc
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime as datetime


# Get OHLC data from kraken api [time,open,high,low,close,vwap,volume,count]

ticker='XXBTZEUR'   
period='5'      
starting='1505677500'

parameters={"pair":ticker,"interval":period,"since":starting}
response=requests.get("https://api.kraken.com/0/public/OHLC", params=parameters)
krakohlc=response.json()['result'][ticker]

ohlc=[]

for i in range(len(krakohlc)):
ohlcdata=krakohlc[i][0:5]
ohlc.append(ohlcdata)       #Make data array (time,O,H,L,C)


labels = ['Date', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close']
ohlc_df=pd.DataFrame.from_records(ohlc, columns=labels)


print(ohlc_df)

#Making plot area
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((6,1), (0,0), rowspan=6, colspan=1)


#Making candlestick plot
candlestick_ohlc(ax1,ohlc_df.values,width=1, colorup='g', colordown='k',alpha=0.75)
ax1.xaxis_date()
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d'))
ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(mticker.MaxNLocator(10))
ax1.grid(True)

plt.xlabel("Date")
plt.ylabel("Price")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: You're getting a type error: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'`. So it sounds like the types of the columns in your dataframe are not what you'd expect them to be. Check them.

Comment: Thanks @Paul H, that was it, the API was delivering strings into the list. I changed line 21 to:    `krakohlc_str=response.json()['result'][ticker]
    krakohlc = [list(map(float, x)) for x in krakohlc_str]`  to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess there are several issue here. The first one, which also produces the error, is that the data is strings, not numbers.

```
# cast data to float
ohlc_df = ohlc_df.astype(float)
```

Then for plotting with matplotlib, one would also need to convert the timestamps to a format which matplotlib can recognize as dates. This could be done as

```
# convert timestamp column to matplotlib date numbers
f = lambda x: mdates.date2num(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(x))
ohlc_df[labels[0]] = ohlc_df[labels[0]].apply(f)
```

Finally the width of the candles should not be one day, but roughly the difference between successive datetime values, in this case 5 minutes,

```
candlestick_ohlc(ax1,ohlc_df.values,width=1./(24*60)*5)
```

Complete example:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from mpl_finance import candlestick_ohlc
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime as datetime

# Get OHLC data from kraken api [time,open,high,low,close,vwap,volume,count]
ticker='XXBTZEUR'   
period='5'      
starting='1505677500'

parameters={"pair":ticker,"interval":period,"since":starting}
response=requests.get("https://api.kraken.com/0/public/OHLC", params=parameters)
krakohlc=response.json()['result'][ticker]

ohlc=[]

for i in range(len(krakohlc)):
    ohlcdata=krakohlc[i][0:5]
    ohlc.append(ohlcdata)       #Make data array (time,O,H,L,C)

labels = ['Date', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close']
ohlc_df=pd.DataFrame.from_records(ohlc, columns=labels)
# cast data to float
ohlc_df = ohlc_df.astype(float)
# convert timestamp column to matplotlib date numbers
f = lambda x: mdates.date2num(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(x))
ohlc_df[labels[0]] = ohlc_df[labels[0]].apply(f)

#Making plot area
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((6,1), (0,0), rowspan=6, colspan=1)

#Making candlestick plot
width = 1./(24*60)*5  # make candles 5 minutes wide
candlestick_ohlc(ax1,ohlc_df.values,width=width, colorup='g', colordown='k',alpha=0.75)
ax1.xaxis_date()
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'))
ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.HourLocator(byhour=[0,12]))
fig.autofmt_xdate()
ax1.grid(True)

plt.xlabel("Date")
plt.ylabel("Price")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Much cleaner way of converting the data to float. Timestamp was on my list of things to do. Thanks there too for the code.